# Providing time and current status as an output prior to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

`@JobTable` will provide a column 'JobStatus', using classic RAG. If it's AMBER or RED, there will be an output below from the @JobTable temp table. I would like it so the user can see from that first table: the result of the check, and what time they were run (It will go into a scheduler and run every hour)

Daily checks are 8am to 7pm
Morning checks are 7am

This script will be added to a scheduler so it would be nice to get the `else 'Daily'` to become The time of the current check

```
DECLARE @RunTime INT

set @RunTime = DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE())

DECLARE @JobTable AS TABLE
  (
     Country    VARCHAR(255),
     JobType    INT,
     JobStatus    NVARCHAR(255),
     JobMessage NVARCHAR(max)
  ) 


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @JobTable WHERE JobStatus = 'RED')
        BEGIN
            select (case
                    WHEN @RunTime BETWEEN 8 AND 9
                    THEN 'Morning'
                    else 'Daily'
                     end) + ' checks are RED' [OLTP Jobs Status]
        END
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @JobTable WHERE JobStatus = 'AMBER')
        BEGIN
            select (case
                    WHEN @RunTime BETWEEN 8 AND 9
                    THEN 'Morning'
                    else 'Daily'
                     end) + ' checks are AMBER' [OLTP Jobs Status]
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            select (case
                    WHEN @RunTime BETWEEN 8 AND 9
                    THEN 'Morning'
                    else 'Daily'
                     end) + ' checks are GREEN'  [OLTP Jobs Status]
        END
```

Output is currently:
[image: output]

So how do I change the below SQL to remove the excess `select (case` and relate the `@RunTime` to the output

At a glance, the user should see eg. "12:00 Checks are AMBER", "Morning Checks are RED", "17:00 Checks are GREEN" (time for all except "morning")

Answer (score 1):

I am confused about your code and your goal. You never populate your table variable so it should procedure the same output regadless of when it runs. But perhaps you cut out some important logic?

Moving on, if there are multiple rows in the table having different values for JobStatus, your code will only produce a single result. Is that intended? If you want to see "12:00 " rather than "Daily" then simply cast the hour variable to a string. Perhaps capturing the exact time would be better?

```
select case WHEN @RunTime BETWEEN 8 AND 9
            THEN 'Morning'
            else cast(@RunTime as varchar(2)) 
   end + ':00 checks are GREEN'  [OLTP Jobs Status]
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=27d0107448a93c12e586fc9e235c6161) to demonstrate.

Comment: The JobTable pulls from a talbe in the system, pulling sproc run details (deadlocks/timeouts) Not fully pertinent here, but there are red,amber,green values associated with them. And yes, The "overall" check will look for red, and display that if red is the "highest" error.  Could we change to capture exact time?

Comment: Then simply replace `cast(@RunTime as varchar(2))` with `convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)` - that is a quick & dirty method but should be ok with this logic.